# Hibernate Search Configuration Help

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, hibernate-search

I am trying to configure hibernate search for my application by reading several web tutorials, the majority uses annotation but I uses xml mapping, also, many tutorial are saying to use spring and maven while I don't uses these.

Can someone help and provide some starting point for configuring hibernate search, many web tutorial are not working for me

The application is a gwt application using gilead with hibernate on the back end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e43

> Hibernate Search, however, has itself its own set of annotations (@Indexed, @DocumentId, @Field,...) for which there exists so far no alternative configuration.

I also remember seeing something like this in "Hibernate Search in Action", where the author said that there's not much demand for non-annotation configuration (I don't have my copy now, so, I may be wrong). I guess that there is still not enough demand.

Note that Hibernate itself can be configured via XML, and I assume that you can mix both (XML for Hibernate mappings, annotations for Hibernate Search mappings).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the previous answer, Hibernate Search does not have a xml configuration. You can configure Hibernate via xml, but not Search. Since Hibernate Search 3.3 there is an alternative, however, which is the programmatic configuration api - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi

There is an object called *SearchMapping*. Once instantiated it offers an fluent API to configure Search the same way you would do with annotations. Add the configured *SearchMapping* instance to your Hibernate *Configuration* instance using the key *hibernate.search.model_mapping* and Search will automatically bootstrap together with Hibernate Core. There is not much to it. You don't need Spring.

Once Search is running you probably want to write a few lines of code to index your existing database. There is code for that in the online manual.

Last, but not least you need some searches. Have a look how to create a *FulltextQuery*. Your system probably gets some sort of search input in what for so ever. Your task is to transform the search input from the "frontend" into a Lucene query which you can then pass to Search in order to execute the search and return managed objects.

Last, but not least - maven is a completely different thing. Now we are talking build systems. Using maven you can get automatically download the artifacts from the JBoss Maven repository. However, there are also dist bundles on SourceForge is this is more what you are after. Check http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search/download for Search download information.

Hope this helps.